# Wordpress menu - dropdown with content, how to accomplish?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to accomplish something in my theme.

First check out the main menu of this site: http://www.tabletmag.com/

As you can see, when you hover on for example News&Politics item, some recent posts, authors etc. come up. And they are dynamically integrated to wordpress.

I want to accomplish the same thing, but I just can't figure out the way to make it happen. What do you think about the way to begin? What's the technique under this menu system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The site seems to be using megamenu plugin. Try  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/